# "Fatal error: Index out of range" when accessing elements in an array, in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swiftui

In swiftUI I was trying to create an array containing items from a multiplication table. (1 x 1 = 1, 1 x 2 = 2, etc), and display some of them to the user.

So I first created a Struct

```
struct TableItem {

        var serialNumber: Int

        var numberA: Int
        var numberB: Int

        var result: Int {
           return numberA * numberB
        }

        init(giveNumberA:Int, giveNumberB:Int, giveSerialNumber: Int) {
            self.numberA = giveNumberA
            self.numberB = giveNumberB
            self.serialNumber = giveSerialNumber
    }
 }
```

Then created the Initialization function within the ContentView, and a View trying to display a random item from the array:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State private var allTableItems = [TableItem]()

@State private var currentDebug = Int.random(in: 0...10)

let tableUpperLimit = 13


var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView{
        VStack{
            Text("\(allTableItems[currentDebug].numberA) * \(allTableItems[currentDebug].numberB) = ?")
                .padding()
                .font(.title)
            
            Text("some other texts")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("edutainment")
        .onAppear(perform: InitializeTheTable)
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                            Button(action: InitializeTheTable) {
                                Text("Reset")
                                }
                        )
    }

    

}


func InitializeTheTable() {
    //Step 1: initialize the full table
    var initCounter = 0
    
    for i in 1 ..< tableUpperLimit {
        for j in i ..< tableUpperLimit {
            
            let tempItem  = TableItem(giveNumberA: i, giveNumberB: j, giveSerialNumber: initCounter)
            
            allTableItems.insert(tempItem, at: initCounter)
            
            //This is for debug purpose
            print("\(initCounter):  \(allTableItems[initCounter].numberA) * \(allTableItems[initCounter].numberB) = \(allTableItems[initCounter].result) \n")
            
            initCounter+=1
        }
    }
}
```

It calls InitializeTheTable() when the view loads, using two for loops to insert itesm into the array, start from "1*1" and ends at "12*12" in this design.

From the console log I can see there are approx 70+ items inserted into the array "allTableItems" as expected.

However in the VStack when I try to extract one random item (index:currentDebug) from the arry and display as a Text, I got an "Fatal error: Index out of range".

The code can build, but it will crash and won't run. Wondering why the array got an "out of range" error? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when the `Text` property in `VStack` is initialized before the `.onAppear (perform: InitializeTheTable)` function.
I've come up with an idea to solve this problem
Before money you create 2 variables in Struct ContentView:

```
@State private var numberA = 0 // <--- here
@State private var numberB = 0 // <--- here
```

Then in the InitializeTheTable func at the end of the loop we do the following:

```
numberA = allTableItems[currentDebug].numberA
numberB = allTableItems[currentDebug].numberB
```

To assign values to numberA and numberB with @State these 2 variables will be refreshed on the interface

```
func InitializeTheTable() {
    //Step 1: initialize the full table
    var initCounter = 0
    
    for i in 1 ..< tableUpperLimit {
        for j in i ..< tableUpperLimit {
            
            let tempItem  = TableItem(giveNumberA: i, giveNumberB: j, 
giveSerialNumber: initCounter)
            
            allTableItems.insert(tempItem, at: initCounter)
            
            //This is for debug purpose
            print("\(initCounter):  \(allTableItems[initCounter].numberA) * \ 
(allTableItems[initCounter].numberB) = \(allTableItems[initCounter].result) \n")
            
            initCounter+=1
        }
    }
    
    numberA = allTableItems[currentDebug].numberA // <--- here
    numberB = allTableItems[currentDebug].numberB // <--- here
}
```

Please update the code

```
Text("\(allTableItems[currentDebug].numberA) * \(allTableItems[currentDebug].numberB) = ?")
            .padding()
            .font(.title) // <-- Old
Text("\(numberA) * \(numberB) = ?")
            .padding()
            .font(.title) // <-- New
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that new solution, and for pointing out where the problem is from. It helps a lot!